# Sqlite Get sum Columns based on another column

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

I have a SQLite table data like this given below.

```
ID    Type    Amount
-----------------------
1     A       10
1     B       5
2     A       4
2     B       7
3     A       2
3     B       8
```

What i wanted to present in a datagridview is something like this

```
ID   A   B
-------------
1   10   5
2    4   7    
3    2   8
```

This is in SQLite database. I need to show the data in datagridview. Currently i am taking the first dataset and using code to loop through to get the desired result but the table has a lot of results and therefore the process is extremely slow.

Can you guys please tell me how can i get the second result directly. I have search but i could not find any appropriate sql query to get this result

Comment: Why the downvote? Its sad. Beginners come here for help nothing else. Stack overflow taught me a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a conditional aggregation

```
select  ID,
        sum(case when Type = 'A' then Amount) as A
        sum(case when Type = 'B' then Amount) as B
from    yourTable
group by ID
```

Another option is to join the table with itself

```
select  ID, t1.Amount as A, t2.Amount as B
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.ID = t2.ID
where   t1.Type = 'A' and
        t2.Type = 'B'
```

The first option requires you to have only one row per ID / Type, but if that's the case performs better. The second one is safer, but joining the table with itself will decrease its performances

Comment: In your second option, shouldn't the 'B' value be taken from t.2 ?

Comment: Awesome. Works Perfectly. Thanks for the options. Might need it in special cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as B 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a pivot table :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{   
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "A", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "B", 5});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "A", 14});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "B", 7});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "A", 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "B", 8});

            string[] uniqueTypes = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Type")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

            foreach (string _type in uniqueTypes)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(_type, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();

                newRow["ID"] = group.Key;

                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    newRow[row.Field<string>("Type")] = row.Field<int>("Amount");
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```